# getting error 'Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect' when i am trying to run jmeter script in visual studio team service.

Tags: visual-studio, jmeter

When i am running jmeter scrpt via Visual studio team services, error 'HttpError Non HTTP response code: java.net.ConnectException Agent000 | Thread Group | 4 /login/login.aspx | Non HTTP response message: Connection timed out: connect' is thrown for all the samplers.
number of thread is-1
loop count- forever

However when i run the same script locally it runs successfully.

Just to add more: 'warning-jmeter.util.SSLManager: Keystore file not found, loading empty keystore' is also thrown before the error comes. does this have to do anything with failing requests?

Comment: Maybe your server is not accessible remotely due to various reasons like Firewall, though locally accessible. first, confirm whether the server you are hitting is accessible manually using a browser.

Comment: Yes as i mentioned i can access the site from local and also if i run jmeter locally the script gets executed successfully. Can it be ssl certificate issue?

Comment: track the requests using network sniffer tools such as Wireshark, and analyse the requests when sent by browser and when sent by JMeter. This would probably give you the idea where the request is failing during connection.

Comment: And i also suggest you check your browser proxy settings and Visual Studio proxy settings. Both should be same, otherwise change Visual Studio proxy setting to match with Browser proxy settings, because though browser you are able to access the server.

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that users know it is usable. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your targeted website available publicly ?

If not, then it's your problem.

Try accessing it from outside your company, if it fails , it will confirm your issue.